# append() fail to make boostrap component works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This drive me crazy, i've this simple html bootstrap-gentelella template that works almost in every page of the site that im developing, the html is so simple:
(this code make the part in the class "x_content" visible or not visible by clicking the "collapse-link" class in the "a" tag)

```
<div class="x_panel">
    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
        <li>
            <a class="collapse-link freccia_feed">Replies
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="x_content" style="display: none;">
        <div class="input-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input data-role="tagsinput" id="risposta_'+j+'_D_'+element+'" class="form-control risposta_domanda_'+element+'" name="reply" value="" placeholder="Insert one solution" type="text">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button  id="elimina_risp_'+j+'_D_'+element+'" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" > </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

be carefull that the part like `id="risposta_'+j+'_D_'+element+'"` have no sense in this static part, and rendered as is it, just for example, I use that in the jQuery function that fail to make it works!
here:

```
 $("#domanda_"+element).append(
                        '<div class="x_panel">'+
                        '<ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">'+
                        '<li>'+
                        '<a class="collapse-link freccia_feed" >Replies'+
                        '<i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>'+
                        '</a></li></ul>'+
                        '<div class="x_content" style="display: none;">'+
                        '<div class="input-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">'+
                        '<input data-role="tagsinput" id="risposta_'+j+'_D_'+element+'" class="form-control risposta_domanda_'+element+'" name="reply"'+
                        'value="" placeholder="Insert one solution" type="text">'+
                        '<span class="input-group-btn"><button  id="elimina_risp_'+j+'_D_'+element+'" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" >'+
                        '</button></span>'+
                        '</div></div></div>');
```

I've tried many options to make this string works inside append() and the only one that seems working it to wrap the whole string with single `'` using double `"` for ids class etc. and then inject javascript variable with single `'` and `+`. Same thing for new line.
I even try to escape the whole string with online escape tools like https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html

but still the same result, the component not works if is appended!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the "inizialization" of the class ".collapse-link" by gentelella js.

So i move the function under my "div" generation function's.
I even add a "unbind()" func to resolve the problem that "inizialization" can toggle even the allready rendered div making them open anc closing several time...
thats the code if someone can find it usefull
cheers

```
                $(".collapse-link").unbind("click");

                $(".collapse-link").on("click", function() {
                    var a = $(this).closest(".x_panel")
                            , b = $(this).find("i")
                            , c = a.find(".x_content");
                    a.attr("style") ? c.slideToggle(200, function() {
                        a.removeAttr("style")
                    }) : (c.slideToggle(200),
                            a.css("height", "auto")),
                            b.toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down")
                });
```